Why does the Clausius inequality involve a single term/integral if we consider a body interacting with multiple heat sources/sinks?
I see that the Clausius inequality was derived for a system interacting with multiple bodies at temperatures $T_{1}, T_{2}, \ldots, T_{n}$ and heat exchanges $\delta Q_{1}, \delta Q_{2}, \ldots, \delta Q_{n}$.
I see the inequality presented as a single integral
$$ \oint \frac{\delta Q}{T} \le 0, $$
but if it is multiple bodies at different bodies, shouldn't it be written as
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\oint \frac{\delta Q_{i}}{T_{i}} \le 0? $$
I don't understand why it is written as a single integral with a single $\delta Q/T$ term. I see various textbooks, such as Don Lemons's Mere Thermodynamics, deriving the inequality for multiple bodies interacting with a system and then jumping to a single integral with only one term. Am I correct something is missing? If yes, how can we bridge the logical gap?

@BobD My assumption is that the integral is over a cycle/process, but it does not sum over the "heat channels" or over the "boundary of the system." I did think maybe it did, but I'd need this pointed out explicitly.

Note the circle on the integral sign. It means the integral is calculated over a cycle. Now, what is it in a heat engine (or a heat pump) that goes through a cycle? It is the working fluid: the gas/liquid that flows through the components of the system and receives or gives heat or work.
Why do I emphasize that?
In the alternative notation that you suggested, you put a circle on the integral of each $\frac{\delta Q_i}{T_i}$, which means you assumed each of those $i$'s represents a cyclic process. But that is not true. The cycle is the set of all of those processes.

This helped clarify Chet Miller's answer, so I'll give this a green checkmark.

The $\delta Q_i's$ are not for different sources at the same time through the process; they assume that, at any one time, there is only one heat source or sink.  The subscripted heats are for different times through the process,, and the summation is replaced by an integral as the increments become smaller.

Clausius inequality. Clausius inequality contains physical quantities of the system of interest, i.e. in
$$\oint_{\ell} \frac{\delta Q}{T} \le 0 \ ,$$
$T$ is the temperature of the system (temperature assumed to be homogeneous), and $\delta Q$ is the heat flux "entering" the system, i.e. $\delta Q > 0$ makes the energy of the system increase. The integral is performed over a loop, $\ell$, of the thermodynamic state of the system.
"Direction" of heat transfer. Being heat transferring energy from hot to cold bodies, the following holds
$$\begin{aligned}
\delta Q_{1 \rightarrow 2} & \ge 0 \quad \text{if} \quad T_1 \ge T_2 \\
\delta Q_{1 \rightarrow 2} & \le 0 \quad \text{if} \quad T_1 \le T_2 \ \end{aligned}$$
or equivalently, summarizing both conditions,
$$\delta{Q}_{1 \rightarrow 2}\left(\frac{1}{T_2} - \frac{1}{T_1} \right) \ge 0 \ .$$
From Clausius inequality to temperature of external systems. Now, it's possible to go back to Clausius inequality and write the heat flux as the sum of the head fluxes exchanged with the different sources, $\delta Q = \sum_i \delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys}$. For every heat flux the following holds,
$$\delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys} \left( \frac{1}{T_{sys}} - \frac{1}{T_i} \right) > 0 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{\delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys}}{T_{sys}} > \frac{\delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys}}{T_i}$$
and thus Clausius inequality gives
$$0 \ge \oint_{\ell} \frac{\delta Q}{T} = \oint_{\ell} \sum_i \frac{\delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys}}{T_{sys}} \ge \oint_{\ell} \sum_i \frac{\delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys}}{T_{i}} \ .$$
If heat exchange happens with one source at a time, you can split the loop $\ell$ in the union of sections $\ell_k$, so that $\ell = \cup_k \ell_k$ and, putting $\delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys} = 0$ when $k \ne i$, you get
$$0 \ge \oint_{\ell} \frac{\delta Q}{T} \ge \sum_i \int_{\ell_i}  \frac{\delta Q_{i \rightarrow sys}}{T_{i}} \ .$$

The logic of this post is airtight. However, when you said, $T$ is the temperature of the system, did you mean at the boundary of the system and surroundings? Other sources say it is the boundary (not necessarily the system itself). See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/269407 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/816987

I dare not tell that Fermi is wrong, but here the system has homogeneous properties, as often happens in thermodynamics of systems in equilibrium, and thus temperature $T(\mathbf{r},t) = T(t)$ of all the points of the system is the same. It's possible to approach the problem with continuous mechanics exploiting the concept of local equilibrium: doing so, entropy flux through the boundary reads $\oint_{\partial V}\frac{\mathbf{q}}{T} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}$, where $T$ is the local temperature at the boundary and $\mathbf{q}$ is the flux through it


Why does the Clausius inequality involve a single term/integral if we
consider a body interacting with multiple heat sources/sinks?

The short answer is the integral allows you to do both discrete sources as well as a continuous distribution of multiple sources.
As Enrico Fermi put it in his book "Thermodynamics":
"In establishing
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{Q_i}{T_i}\le0$$
we assumed the system exchanges heat with a finite number of sources $T_{1}$, $T_{2}$, ....,$T_{n}$. It is important, however, to consider the case for which the system exchanges heat with a continuous distribution of sources. In that case, the sums must be replaced by integrals extended over the entire system cycle."
I would add that as an example of exchanging "heat with a continuous distribution of sources", consider a reversible isochoric heat addition of an ideal gas which requires exchanging heat with an infinite series of thermal reservoirs ranging from the initial to final temperature. The differential change in entropy is given by
$$dS=\frac{C_{v}dT}{T}$$
For a total change in entropy of
$$\Delta S=\int_{Ti}^{Tf}\frac{C_{v}dT}{T}=C_{v}\ln\frac{T_f}{T_i}$$
Hope this helps.
